# Avoid non-readonly static fields Rule

Tags: csv, ndepend

I'm reviewing with NDepend some code I wrote few time ago and I ended up on this warning

[image]

The warning is referred on the following snippt

```
    private static char csvSeparator;

    public static char CsvSeparator => csvSeparator != Char.MinValue
        ? csvSeparator
        : (csvSeparator =
            ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.Instance.AppSettings.Get("csv_separator", ';'));
```

The idea that this piece of code was based on was that I have a separator character defined in the app.config then this one will be the same for the whole application lifetime. My code reads it and then it stores in a static variable for future use.This application is a console one that creates with high-frequency CSV file so I don't want to waste time reading it from the config file each time I need it.

Can you please provide me a solution to that warning?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid any problem you should make sure that the static field `csvSeparator` field is only assigned by the **class constructor method** of your class. This way not only you'll be able to set your field as `readonly`, but also the rule won't warn anymore.

```
static YourClassName() {
   //  csvSeparator  gets assigned 
   csvSeparator = csvSeparator != Char.MinValue
        ? csvSeparator
        : (csvSeparator = ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.Instance.AppSettings.Get("csv_separator", ';'));
}

private static readonly  char csvSeparator;

public static char CsvSeparator => csvSeparator;
```

or you could also use a backing field and an auto property getter

Comment: Excuse me, what you mean for backing field and auto property getter

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me if I don't comment but since I need to paste code I can't do on comment... btw this solution should work as well (and I don't need a private prop)

```
public static readonly char CsvSeparator;
static Helper()
    {
        CsvSeparator = ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.Instance.AppSettings.Get("csv_separator", ';');
    }
```